# Java overriden methods only gets called when there is a call to System.out.println

Tags: java, overriding, mouselistener

The following are two methods on an object I've created. The superclass has implemented MouseListener.

```
@Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
    mIsPushed = true;
    System.out.println("Button pushed");
  }

  @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
    mIsPushed = false;
    System.out.println("Button released");
  }
```

When the two `System.out.println` calls are uncommented, the program works fine and behaves as it should. When they aren't, it does nothing. I have even placed breakpoints at the `mIsPushed` assignments and they're never reached.

However, if I put a breakpoint at the point where these two functions are called, the debugger reaches it and the calls are made.

Can anyone tell me what I've missed?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect you're doing something dodgy like trying to use a shared variable from multiple threads with no protection from stale values, but we can't say without seeing more code.

Comment: That would be my bet too, since the print-statement are basically a no-op in all other regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to the different threads caching their own values of the `mIsPushed` variable.

You need to **synchronize** the access to this variable. You have a few different options:

- Declare it as `volatile`
- Use some high level construct from `java.util.concurrent` package (such as `AtomicBoolean`)
- Synchronize the access to the variable using the `synchronized` keyword.

---

In more detail: The Java memory model does not guarantee that a *read* of a variable from one thread will yield the last value *written* to that variable from another thread. This is to allow a JVM to optimize the execution of a Java program. Adding a `System.out.println` may flush the cache and cause a new value to be loaded when needed.

To explicitly tell the JVM to make sure that no cached value should be used, you need to introduce a "happens before"-relation between the write and the read.

Further reading:

- [Java Language Specification: Threads and Locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. The possibility that it would be caused by multiple threads didn't, but should have, occur to me. I added synchronized on all associated methods and the problem is resolved.